# error in file "mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" in magento 1.9.2.0 installation with sample data

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am trying to install Magento version 1.9.2.0 with the sample data in my local Apache server.

I have stumbled upon a problem that is tearing my heart appart and I need some help or guidance in this obscure path, for I get this error message:

```
Error in file: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend

/sql/sendfriend_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_magento_sample.sendfriend_log' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `sendfriend_log`

Trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.1')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.1')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I have tried changing the directories permissions, I have already uploaded the sql sample data script to my local DB using PHPMyAdmin, erasing and reinstalling again, and restarting the process for more than 3 times but I got blocked here, I have searched for solutions in forums but haven't found none

Does anyone know how to proceed? I thank you for reading.
Best regards,
D.

Comment: I don't use magento but my presumption is that  `sendfriend_log` doesn't exist..

Comment: @chris85 - and that presumption is correct, the table is not there and needs to be created so the installer upgrade script will run. It can't upgrade what isn't there.

Comment: You mention _I am trying to install Magento version 1.9.2.0 with the sample data in my local Apache server._ What you say later isn't very clear on this => Did you follow proper order for using Magento's test data? 1) create a database in MySQL with access credentials, 2) import Magento test data into that database **and 3) finally as the last step, then install Magento,** giving it the credentials of the pre-created, pre-loaded database with the test data? If not, wipe everything and restart. If you don't follow the proper order on this, you get all sorts of odd results.

Comment: What's content of : `/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sendfriend/sql/sendfriend_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your recommendations. I just restarted the whole process again and it somehow worked, maybe I had changed the name accidentally on one of the installation directories.